# C++ How to call a child function from a parent function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, parent-child

I have a parent class called `List` and a child class called `SortedList`. In `List`, I overload `+=` so that it calls the member function `Insert`. That is:

```
void List::operator+=(std::string newEntry) {    
    this->Insert(newEntry);  
}
```

Both `List` and `SortedList` have an `Insert` function. Ideally, if the instance of `List` that I'm using is also a `SortedList`, `SortedList`'s `Insert` function would be called instead of `List`'s, but that's not what is happening. I could redefine the above function in `SortedList` and every subsequent child class of `List` that I will create, but that seems redundant. Is there any way to modify the above function to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't heard of virtual methods before. All I had to do was add `virtual` in front of `List`'s `Insert` function declaration.